# How to burn a sewer network into a DEM

Tags: dem, watershed, arc-hydro

As part of the sewershed delineation using the ArcHydro toolbox in ArcGIS Pro, I need to burn my sewer network into the DEM to recondition it based on pipe elevations. I have calculated and added the z-values to my network using upstream and downstream invert elevations. Does anyone know the next steps for burning my network into the DEM?

Comment: Make copy of pipes, density by 1 cell of your DEM values, use feature to 3d using inverts. Extract vertices, add Z information. Convert to raster and overlay on DEM. I'd also convert cells under main outlets into nodata.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Could you please let me know how I can create a density of my DEM? and why I should extract vertices? Can't I convert my pipelines including Z values into a raster and then overlay it with my DEM? and what about the manholes?

Comment: Densify pipes, densification distance equal cell size of your DEM.